# java collections stores values or references?

Tags: java, collections, reference

Beginner Java question: when I have

```
Integer i = 6;
ArrayList<Integer> ar = ArrayList<Integer>();
ar.add(i);
```

then I write `i = 8`, `ar.get(0)` returns `6`.

But if I trie the same thing with a class of mine:

```
class MyC
{
    Integer i;
}
MyC myc = new MyC();
myc.i = 6;
ArrayList<MyC> ar = ArrayList<MyC>();
ar.add(myc);
```

then do `myc.i = 8`, `ar.get(0)` returns `8`.

Can you please explain this behavior?

Comment: You're getting confused by autoboxing. `i=8` is a little more complicated than it looks when i is an Integer.

Comment: This is actually a really complicated question even though it looks really simple. Thumbs up to bringing the attention to autoboxing.

Comment: `ar.get(0)` does not return 8. `ar.get(0).i` will return 8.

Comment: Autoboxing has nothing to do with this. The issue is pointing to a different object vs. mutating an object.

Comment: @BrettOkken w/o autoboxing there would be no "different object" to point to, there would be a primitive `int` on stack.

Comment: Even if we were talking about a primitive `int[]`. If you have `int i=8; array[0] = i; i = 6;` The value at `array[0]` would be `8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `i = 8` is turned by the compiler into `i = new Integer(8)`, since `i` is of `Integer` type, not `int`, so you have 2 references now. In your second example, there's still one reference referenced from both `myc` and first element of `ar`.

As pointed out by Sotirios in comment, if `i` was primitive, you'll get the same result. But because of slightly different reason:

```
int i = 6;
ArrayList<Integer> ar = ArrayList<Integer>();
ar.add(i);
i = 8; // changes not a ref, but value on stack
System.out.println(ar.get(0)); // prints out 6
```

Here you have not two references, but one (to autoboxed `Integer` inside `ar`).

Comment: I feel like your answer is misleading readers into thinking that if `i` was an `int` the result would be different.

Comment: You right that result would be the same. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has nothing to do with autoboxing, as some answers say.

In the first example you create an Integer and put it in the `ArrayList`.
Then you change the pointer to the Integer, so that `i` is pointing to another Integer.
This don't affects the Integer of the `ArrayList`.

In the second example you create an object and put it in the `ArrayList`.
Then you change the state of this object by `myc.i = 8`.
This way the object in the `ArrayList` is changed.

Answer (score 2):

All variables, with the exception of primitive types, store references, not values.

**First example**

```
Integer i = 6;
```

Create a new `Integer` object (lets call it **I1**) and store a reference to it in `i`

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar = ArrayList<Integer>();
ar.add(i);`
```

Create an `ArrayList`, and store a reference to **I1** in it

```
i = 8;
```

Create a new (different) `Integer` object (lets call it **I2**) and store a reference to it in `i`

So now, `i` = **I2**, and `ar.get(0)` = **I1**

**Second example**

```
MyC myc = new MyC();
```

Create a new `MyC` (let's call it **C**) and store a reference to in in `myc`

```
myc.i = 6;
```

Create a new `Integer` object (lets call it **I1**) and store a reference to it in **C**.`i`

```
ArrayList<MyC> ar = ArrayList<MyC>();
ar.add(myc);
```

Create an `ArrayList`, and store a reference to **C** in it.

```
myc.i = 8
```

Create a new `Integer` object (lets call it **I2**) and store a reference to it in **C**.`i`

So now `myc` = **C**, `myc.i` = **I2**, `ar.get(0)` = **C**, and therefore `ar.get(0).i` = **I2**.

Nothing is referencing **I1** and it will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` is an Object-wrapper around the primitive type of `int`.

In order to store them in a `Collection` for example `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()`, the stored element type needs to be a subclass of Object. Therefore, they are stored by reference, as all Objects are stored as references (and all methods receive references by value, see [Parameter passing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570360/parameter-passing-in-java/24570621#24570621) )

It is important to note that in the case of

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(5);
int number = list.get(0);
System.out.println("" + number);
```

The reason why 5 can be used to add the number is because of auto-boxing. When you get the number from the list, it also implicitly calls .intValue() and returns the value of the wrapper as a primitive int. Then in the println() function, the number is implicitly boxed to Integer and then toString() is called.

Answer (score 0):

All variables in Java are references that refer to objects that live out on the heap.

The wrapper classes (e.g. Integer) are special cases.  Those implement the Flyweight pattern and are immutable.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem of autoboxing. In the first example the pointer to i is changed after inserting, in the second example the object myc itself is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Pointing `i` to a different object does not mutate the (original) object. This is not special to primitives. Say you have a `List<List<Object>>` or a `List<List<String>>`:

```
        List<List<String>> wrapper = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        wrapper.add(l1);

        l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        l1.add("hello");
        for(List<String> list : wrapper)
        {
            for(String string : list)
            {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
```

If you now iterate over `wrapper` you find it contains 1 empty list. This is equivalent to your first example. Your second example looks like:

```
        List<List<String>> wrapper = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        wrapper.add(l1);

        l1.add("hello");
        for(List<String> list : wrapper)
        {
            for(String string : list)
            {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
```

In this case the `wrapper` now contains 1 list with one value in it.

Comment: Right, because you're storing the original ArrayList in the wrapper, and then you just modify the reference of the variable. But that's not actually the original ArrayList that was stored in the wrapper.